# URL monitoring over HTTP (internal)

Tags: json, mongodb, health-monitoring

I have a large (2-3K) list URLs (accessible only internally). The content type of the HTTP response for these URLs is JSON.

At the moment I just have a script that checks each URL every 5 minutes and stores a JSON output in MongoDB.

Instead of using custom build script, I'd like to use a tool that perhaps is more suitable for such task.

I need to be able:

1. Add new, pause, remove URLs programatically (over API)
2. Be able to store JSON output in the database
3. Create dashboards based on the JSON data in the database

I briefly looked at graphite & collectd, influxdb & telegraf, but not sure if it's a good choice.

Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB sounds like a poor choice, since your data is mostly text, and is only loosely bound to the time dimension. Why not use a traditional SQL store? Alternately, this is a problem the ELK stack might address more easily.